# What theorem in topology was Claude Shannon referring to?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, signal-processing, information-theory

In 1949, in a classic paper, [Claude Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Shannon)$^\color{red}{\star}$wrote the following:

> As we change the message a small amount, the corresponding signal will change a small amount, until some critical value is reached. At this point the signal will undergo a considerable change. In topology it is shown that it is not possible to map a region of higher dimension into a region of lower dimension *continuously*. It is the necessary discontinuity which produces the threshold effects we have been describing for communication systems.

Emphasis is Shannon's. I assume Shannon is referring to a very well-known theorem in topology. Can anyone tell me which theorem that is?

---

<sub>$\color{red}{\star}$ Claude Elwood Shannon, [Communication in the Presence of Noise](https://doi.org/10.1109/JRPROC.1949.232969), Proceedings of the Institute of Radio Engineers, Volume 37, Issue 1, Pages 10-21, January 1949.</sub>

Comment: Some of the ideas are explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: Just from the wording, it looks like it is saying that a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ cannot be mapped continuously and injectively (in)to $\mathbb R^k$ if $k < n$. I think that the proof is not hard, and just uses what nowadays is first year algebraic topology.

Comment: @littleO: Shannon's paper was written long time ago, before the modern terminology became uniformly used. From reading his paper, by a "mapping" he clearly meant an injective mapping (section V of his paper, where he spells out the injectivity condition). Interestingly, by "one-to-one" he meant a *surjective* mapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [**invariance of domain**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). This is usually stated something like:

> If $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism between $U$ and its image.

In particular, the image of any injective continuous map $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Via the usual inclusion map $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ for $m<n$, we get as a corollary that there is no continuous injection from a (nonempty) open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Thank you. Would you say that the algebraic topology tag is applicable?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think it's a borderline case - I'd neither object to nor demand it, personally.

Comment: But the general topology tag is OK, right? I did not even know how to tag the question properly.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo invariance of domain is definitely general topology (first proved by Brouwer, far before algebraic topology had been developed (his proof did inspire some techniques we now associate with it).

Comment: It sounds to me like Shannon was referring to the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$ (unless $m =n$).

Comment: @littleO I think that's ignoring Shannon's use of the term "region." I really think that the full invariance of domain, not just $\mathbb{R}^n\not\cong\mathbb{R}^m$ if $m\not=n$, is what was meant here. But of course this is ultimately impossible to settle.